Docker how to overcome "change of ownership" error of a folder from an external mounted SSD drive
I have a question regarding ownership mapping of folders via the Docker-Compose file.
Shortly to my problem:
I'm using Docker on my RaspiPi 4 and wanted to enter the world of paperless office (paperless-ngx).
Since an SD card is not really known for withstanding many read and write operations, I have purchased an external SSD for this purpose (in other words: if the SD card is lost, all data are still available on the SSD).
As I come from the Windows world, I'm unfortunately not very Linux-orientated and have virtually no knowledge of the structure of this operating system and the assignment of permissions.
I used the file from the Github page as the basis for the Docker-compose file and adapted it (UID and GID to 1000 = Admin, storage location that points to the mounted SSD (/externSSD/docker/)).
services:
  broker:
    image: docker.io/library/redis:7
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /redisdata:/data

  db:
    image: docker.io/library/postgres:16
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: paperless
      POSTGRES_USER: paperless
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: paperless
      

  webserver:
    image: ghcr.io/paperless-ngx/paperless-ngx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8010:8000"
    volumes:
      - /externSSD/docker/paperless-ngx/data:/usr/src/paperless/data
      - /externSSD/docker/paperless-ngx/media:/usr/src/paperless/media
      - /externSSD/docker/paperless-ngx/export:/usr/src/paperless/export
      - /externSSD/docker/paperless-ngx/consume:/usr/src/paperless/consume
    environment:
      PAPERLESS_REDIS: redis://broker:6379
      PAPERLESS_DBHOST: db
      PAPERLESS_SECRET_KEY: SecretKey
      PAPERLESS_ADMIN_USER: admin
      PAPERLESS_ADMIN_PASSWORD: passPaperless
      PAPERLESS_OCR_LANGUAGE: deu+eng
    
      USERMAP_UID: 1000
      USERMAP_GID: 1000
      privledged: true

volumes:
  data:
  media:
  pgdata:
  redisdata:

Problem 1: Paperless-ngx has no permissions to operate with the user Admin on the mounted SSD!
The SSD is formatted as ExFat to be able to save the file via my Mac. Since the SSD gets always mounted with root, I had to mount the SSD statically with the permissions for the admin user (id=1000) (Reddit Post and Mount with permissions).
By mounting with permissions, I was able to solve the problem that Paperless has no permissions to create and manage the folders (Data, Media, Export, Consume) during deployment.
Problem 2: Database and broker should also write to the external SSD and store the data. (Starting with the database)
If I change the storage path to the external SSD in the DockerCompose file:
volumes:
          - /externSSD/docker/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

I get the following error:

chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Operation not
permitted

From the first deploy I saw that the database is created with the user and the group 999. This was then also confirmed to me by my research by other users (Rech1 and Dockerfile Postgres)
As I have already mounted the SSD with the permissions for the user admin (UID and GID=1000), I cannot change the ownership (chown) of "/etxernSSD/docker/pgdata" to 999 after deployment, even in root mode...
Unfortunately, with Postgres you cannot simply assign the UID and GID in the Docker-Compose file, as with Paperless.
USERMAP_UID: 1000
USERMAP_GID: 1000

I am now turning to those who know far more about Linux and Docker than I do. I hope you can help me at this point.
